# UICollectionView does not display the images

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to display a collection of horizontally scrollable images with the help of the UICollectionView . I did a custom view controller file for the cell but i still don`t get any images displayed. This is my code in Viewcontroller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource{

var imageArray = [UIImage(named:"1"),UIImage(named:"2"),UIImage(named:"3"),UIImage(named:"4"),UIImage(named:"5"),UIImage(named:"6"),UIImage(named:"7"),UIImage(named:"8"),]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coffeeImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)   as! coffeeImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.Imgimage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }
}
```

And this is in my custom CollectionViewCell class, to which i linked the image view:

```
import UIKit

 class coffeeImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Imgimage: UIImageView!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The tutorial i used is from 2 years ago and the person is using version 3. I just changed the "!" after "as" to "?" and added a "?" after cell (.image). Also, i added a "!" after return cell to unwrap

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

With creating this outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Comment: I have encountered 2 problems:                                                                     
Firstly,  i could not create the outlet, for some reason when i try no option of creating an outlet appears. Secondly, i get this error when adding the self.collectionView : Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'